# SFML window immediately closes

Tags: c++, sfml

I was following a tutorial on how to make buttons in sfml and then when I ran it, the window immediately closed.I have 2 files, one called main.cpp and the other one called button.h. I cannot find any fix on the internet to fix this issue so how do i fix it?
Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "button.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;
int main(){
    bool isStartOpen = false;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500, 500), "Operating System", Style::Close | Style::Resize);
    RectangleShape player(Vector2f(500.0f, 30.0f));
    RectangleShape startMenu(Vector2f(300.0f, 400.0f));
    Texture startTexture;
    if(!startTexture.loadFromFile("startButton.png")){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading image file: startButton.png in the system", "Image File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    startMenu.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0, 200));
    startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 500.0f);
    player.setFillColor(Color::Black);
    player.setPosition(0.0f, 473.0f);
    Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("buttonFont.ttf")){
       MessageBox(NULL, "Error loading font file: buttonFont.ttf in the system", "Font File Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    Button openNotepad("Open Notepad", {200, 50}, 20, Color::Green, Color::Black);
    openNotepad.setPosition({100, 300});
    openNotepad.setFont(font);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type){
                case Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    cout << "Window has been removed" << endl;
                    break;
                case Event::MouseMoved:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
                      openNotepad.setBackColor(Color::White);
                    }else{
                        openNotepad.setBackColor(Color::Green);
                    }
                    break;
                case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                    if(openNotepad.isMouseOver(window)){
                        cout << "You clicked the button" << endl;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Key::S) && !isStartOpen){
            startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 75.0f);
            isStartOpen = true;
        }else{
            startMenu.setPosition(0.0f, 500.0f);
            isStartOpen = false;
        }
        window.draw(startMenu);
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
        window.clear(Color(1, 159, 255));
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Code for button.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
class Button{
    public:
        Button(){

        }
        Button(string t, Vector2f size, int charSize, Color bgColor, Color textColor){
            text.setString(t);
            text.setColor(textColor);
            text.setCharacterSize(charSize);
            button.setSize(size);
            button.setFillColor(bgColor);
        }
        void setFont(Font &font){
            text.setFont(font);
        }
        void setBackColor(Color color){
            button.setFillColor(color);
        }
        void setTextColor(Color color){
            text.setColor(color);
        }
        void setPosition(Vector2f pos){
            button.setPosition(pos);
            float xPos = (pos.x + button.getLocalBounds().width / 3) - (text.getLocalBounds().width / 2);
            float yPos = (pos.y + button.getLocalBounds().height / 4) - (text.getLocalBounds().height / 2);
            text.setPosition({xPos, yPos});
        }
        void drawTo(RenderWindow &window){
            window.draw(button);
            window.draw(text);
        }
        bool isMouseOver(RenderWindow &window){
            float mouseX = Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
            float mouseY = Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
            float btnPosX = button.getPosition().x;
            float btnPosY = button.getPosition().y;
            float btnxPosWidth = button.getPosition().x + button.getLocalBounds().width;
            float btnyPosWidth = button.getPosition().y + button.getLocalBounds().height;
            if(mouseX < btnxPosWidth && mouseX > btnPosX && mouseY < btnyPosWidth && mouseY > btnPosY){
                return true;
            }
```

There are no errors in the program so how do i fix the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you have a crash? Have you tried to step through your program in a debugger to see what really happens?

Comment: Lesson of the day: Mind your indentation, and keep it consistent. And always look at your braces. A good editor can help you reindent code, making problems like your easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `return 0;` in `while(window.isOpen())`, so your program closes the window immediately, put `return 0;` outside the `while loop`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me and now I can continue coding :)